# Showing text as link in InfoPath form 2013

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

Hi I am creating a InfoPath form using designer 2013. I am struck at a point where I am unable to make a url to show as text which can be clickable in the form once saved. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding a hyperlink:

1. Click on the insert tab on the ribbon
2. Select Hyperlink

[image]

3. FIll out the wizard:

[image]

4. Your url will now display as your text:

[image]